# play sound file with a delay and adjust time in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, android-music-player

I am trying to program a sound app where on button click I would like to play 3-4 sound files one after the other. How can this be done? Also I would like to increase the time of play of the files. Is this where the loop variable in play function used??

Here is part of code I have done with SoundPool. However the files all play simultaneously :(

```
        public void onClick(View v){
            //check for scan button
            if(v.getId()==R.id.playbutton){
                queueSound(1000);
                sound.changePitchfile3(R.raw.a0);
                queueSound(5000);
                sound.changePitchfile2(R.raw.a1);
                queueSound(10000);
                sound.changePitchfile3(R.raw.a3);

            }
        }
    });

}
 private void queueSound(final long delay) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
          }}, delay);

public void changePitchfile1(int res1) {
    int soundId = (Integer) mSounds.get(res1);
    this.myPlayer.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0,1.125f);
}
```

Comment: I believe `SoundPool` does not provide a listener for when the play has finished, so you would have to know the length of your sounds in advance and set up your Handlers accordingly. I would recommend using a `MediaPlayer` with an `onCompleteListener` as an alternative.

Comment: I need to be able to adjust the pitch and therefore I chose SoundPool in the first place. Is this possible with MediaPlayer? Also my sound file is about 6 MB large

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that. No, only `SoundPool` supports pitch change, so you will have to use that. You are on the right track but your call to `changePitchfile1` should be within the `Runnable` - whatever is in the `Runnable()` will execute after the delay.