# android - how to delay an audio file so it starts after a few seconds

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I've been wondering if there's a way with either mp or soundpool to delay a sound and make it start exactly after 10 seconds (I have a countdown and want to add a sound effect saying 3,2,1 go! after 10 seconds.)

Comment: Use `Handler.postDelay` to start MediaPlayer after 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe with a handler?

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        playSound();
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to write this in context to the media player, could someone elaborate? Also if it's a short sound can I use this handler with soundpool?

Comment: you write it where you have playSound, its just wrapped. I dont have experience with soundpool, maybe this the code here can help, even if its not answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687314/play-sound-file-with-a-delay-and-adjust-time-in-android